# MySQL - querying on multiple tables with constraints

Tags: mysql

I have 6 SQL tables

```
TABLE Person ( per_id , name , email , gender , DOB ) 
TABLE Job ( job_id , jp_code , pay_rate , company ) 
TABLE JobProfile ( jp_code , title , description ) 
TABLE Skill ( sk_code , skillName , description )
TABLE Requires ( jp_code , sk_code )
TABLE Possess(per_id, sk_code)
```

From this table,

1. when a person considers a job with a job code , i need to be able to
   pull the skill set he is missing for the job upon his per_id
2. for a given per_id, list all job that he is qualified for
3. for a given per_id, list the job with the maximum salary
4. find all per_id whoa are qualified for a given job_code

I am unable to form a procedure to attack this kind of problem. Often, I end up spending hours on a single task. Clearly, I am missing some directions here. It would be helpful if someone tell me how to approach such problem in SQL.

Comment: Where is the 6. Table?

Comment: TABLE Possess(per_id, sk_code) was missing. Ive been trying to edit the post but I could find the edit post section.

Answer (score 0):

a) 
Person table has no relation to Skill, so there is no way to relate a Skillset to a Person. If you would have some relation between (maybe a new table that telates many sk_codes to many of the same per_id?).

You have to select all sk_codes from that persons skillset. Lets say this is statement X

Then you have to find all the sk_codes required for a job, so given a jp_code select all sk_codes from Requires where the jp_code matches. Statement Y

So now you have X = all sk_codes of a person and Y = all sk_codes needed for a job. Finally select all Skills where sk_code is the subset of these two ( the missing sk_codes a person needs )

b) Very similar to a. Find the persons sk_codes and then find a jp_code from Requires that has all of them and none outstanding.

c) Might be missing more info, given that the job is in the list he is qualified for then we have that from b) simply select max(pay_rate) from Job

d) Find all the sk_codes related to a jp_code and then select all outstanding per_ids

I suggest reading up on [INNER_JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Yes, this is what I have arrived at from today morning. But apparently, things rather complicate when you consider that a Job can have more than one skills, in which a person only qualifies for a job if he/she has both the required skills. How to keep track of that is the new challenge.

Comment: I used a query like so  `select * from Job as JB join Requires as RQ on RQ.jp_code=JB.jp_code and JB.job_id in (select job_id from Job) where RQ.sk_code in (select sk_code from Possess where per_id=1);` and this gets me, all details of jobs which match atleast one skills. How to get it to include job details only when it matches, both the skills ?